# setting a value that can be A or B to a value that is A after checking

Tags: typescript

I have a value that can either be of Type A or B and one that is explicitly A:

```
let valueOptional: A|B;
let valueExplicit: A;
```

Now i do a typecheck and then set the value:

```
if ((typeof valueOptional).toString() === 'B') {
  valueExplicit = convertB2A(valueOptional);
} else {
  valueExplicit = valueOptional;
}
```

Now the compiler still throws this error:

```
Type 'A | B' is not assignable to type 'A'.
  Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'B'.
    Property 'xyz' is missing in type 'B'.
```

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: What are A or B ? That impacts the type of type guard you can use .. for primitives you can use `typeof x === 'number'` for classes you can use `x instanceof A` for interfaces you can use an `in` typeguard `'xyz' in x` ... so it depends. But your above construct `(typeof x).toString() == 'type'` is not a type guard

Comment: `A` is `Params` and `B` is `ParamMap` from angulars router module.
So both are `Types`

Comment: Types are also erased at compiler time, so either a custom type guard or `in` type guard..

Answer (score 3):

If you have a union and you want to narrow the type of the union to one of it's constituents, you need to use a type-guard. What the compiler understands to be a type-guard is limited, and what we can use on a given type also depends on what kind of type we have.

For primitives we can use a `typeof` type guard:

```
let valueOptional: number|string;
let valueExplicit: number;

if (typeof valueOptional === 'number') {
  valueExplicit = valueOptional; // valueOptional is number here
} else {
  valueExplicit = +valueOptional //valueOptional is string and we convert
}
```

For classes we can use an `instanceof` type guard:

```
class A { constructor(public foo: number) { } }
class B { constructor(public bar: number) { } }
let valueOptional: A | B;
let valueExplicit: A;

if (valueOptional instanceof A) {
  valueExplicit = valueOptional; // valueOptional is A here
} else {
  valueExplicit = new A(valueOptional.bar) //valueOptional is B and we convert
}
```

If `A` and `B` are interfaces we can use an `in` type guard to determine the type based on the existence of a property (neither `typeof` or `instanceof` will work since interfaces are not really represented in any way at runtime). An `in` type-guard can alos work with classes but for interfaces it's the only option :

```
interface A { foo: number }
interface B { bar: number }
let valueOptional: A | B;
let valueExplicit: A;

if ('foo' in valueOptional) {
  valueExplicit = valueOptional; // valueOptional is A here
} else {
  valueExplicit = { foo: valueOptional.bar } //valueOptional is B and we convert
}
```

You can also use a custom type guard if you conditions are more complicated:

```
interface A { foo: number }
interface B { foo: string }
let valueOptional: A | B;
let valueExplicit: A;
// any condition that returns true/false will do, used an arrow function but any function that returns param is type will act as a type guard.
const isA = <T>(v: T | A): v is A => typeof (v as A).foo === 'number'; 

if (isA(valueOptional)) {
  valueExplicit = valueOptional; // valueOptional is A here
} else {
  valueExplicit = { foo: +valueOptional.foo } //valueOptional is B and we convert
}
```

You can also mix and match type-guards:

```
interface A { foo: number }
interface B { foo: string }
class C { bar: string }
let valueOptional: number| A | B | C;
let valueExplicit: A;
const isA = <T>(v: T | A): v is A => typeof (v as A).foo === 'number'; 

if (typeof valueOptional === 'number') {
  valueExplicit = { foo: valueOptional }; // valueOptional is number here
}else if(valueOptional instanceof C) {
  valueExplicit = { foo: +valueOptional.bar } //valueOptional is C and we convert
} else if (isA(valueOptional)) {
  valueExplicit = valueOptional //valueOptional is A 
} else {
  valueExplicit = { foo: + valueOptional.foo } //valueOptional is B by elimination and we convert
}
```